# Could Obama have secretly pardoned Hillary?

Tags: united-states, law, constitution, executive, pardon

We heard many news reports of many pardons Obama made. But is it possible Obama could have *secretly* made other pardons as well?

For example, assume Obama pardoned, say, Hillary Clinton, for example: Obama gave Hillary an official, legally binding document with a pardon on it; only Obama did this secretly and neither Obama nor Hillary told anyone about it. Now let's say years later, Hillary gets prosecuted for a "crime against the United States?"

Could Hillary pull out her pardon and play it like a trump card?

Or, more to the point, do we have any way of knowing for certain that Obama did not make any secret *pre-emptive* pardons?

Comment: While the "secret pardon" part is a duplicate, you could perhaps edit your question to just be  about the possibility of a _preemptive_ pardon, which was not answered previously (or at least not in the (now linked) previous answer).

Comment: "like a trump card" could also be spelled "like a Trump card" in this case.